# Echo Child Page & Grandchild Page Count

Tags: php, wordpress

**What I'm trying to do:**

Show count for Child Pages and Grandchild Pages seperately.

So on a parent page it would something like this:

Currently 11 child pages and 34 Grandchild pages.

**My code currently:**

```
<?php
$children = get_pages( array(
'child_of' => $post->ID,
) );
echo count($children);?>
```

It displays a count of total children indiscriminately. WordPress docs tell me that it can be modified using **"'parent' =>"** but I haven't been able to make it work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: If all you want to do is show the count, then to actually `get_pages()` is overkill. Create a method that just does the counting or search for an existing one. I'm not that familiar with WP, but look for example at get_blog_count() http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_blog_count.

Comment: Yea I think you're right. Cheers. I'll try a different approach.

Comment: get_blog_count is not  a good example. But look mayb be at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_hierarchy and/or http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_all_page_ids

Comment: Thanks again dude...I'm also takin a look at this                    wp_count_posts('page'); ..either way, I was barking up the wrong tree with "get_pages"

Answer (score 0):

I would use `wp_list_pages()` and specify the depth.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages

It would take two queries - the first would be of depth=2 and the second would be of depth 3.

The first query would give you the number of child pages (11).

The second query (45) minus the first query (11) would give you the number of grandchild pages. (34).

Hope that helps.